# Подскажите как сократить код? JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я преобразую txt файл в JSОN формат, как то можно сократить подобный код?

```
const updateFile = arrFile
      // Общие изменения
      .replace(/\n+/gi, '\n')
      .replace(/"/gi, "'")
      .replace(/1CClientBankExchange/gi, '{ \n"clientBankExchange" :[{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount1":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount2":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount3":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount4":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount5":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount6":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount7":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount8":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount9":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount10":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount11":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount12":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount13":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount14":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount15":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount16":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount17":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount18":{')
      .replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, '},\n"sectionCalculationAccount19":{')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать вынести в цикл:

```js
let updateFile = arrFile
      // Общие изменения
      .replace(/\n+/gi, '\n')
      .replace(/"/gi, "'")
      .replace(/1CClientBankExchange/gi, '{ \n"clientBankExchange" :[{');
      
for (let i = 0; i < 19; ++i) {
  updateFile = updateFile.replace(/СекцияРасчСчет/, `},\n"sectionCalculationAccount${i + 1}":{`)
}
```